# jQuery, почему $.inArray не добавляет значение при проверке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему `$.inArray` не добавляет значение при проверке?

```js
let data = [];

if(!$.inArray('test', data)) data.push('test');

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Функция $.inArray() возвращает либо индекс найденного значения, либо -1, если не найдено. Соответственно надо вам сравнить с -1

Comment: А почему он должен добавлять что-то?

Comment: @Bear Vorkuta, Спасибо, вопрос решен, думал он должен был возвращать булен тип как в `php` при проверке `in_array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let data = [];


if($.inArray('test', data) === -1) data.push('test');

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```